# Merge 3 bar charts into one

Tags: r

I have three bar charts which I need to have merged into one, where the values will be displayed next to each other (comparing number of companies opened in 3 different years, grouped by months) - this type of logic: https://community.qlik.com/t5/image/serverpage/image-id/37330iA30E2E5966D31DBD/image-size/large?v=1.0&px=999.

Can you, please, suggest a way how to improve my "Create graphs" part, so that it doesn't generate three graphs but one containing data for all three years?

**Dataset:** https://gofile.io/d/ZpbXAB

Thank you!

```
# Install needed packages
install.packages("dplyr")
install.packages("tidyverse")
install.packages("ggplot2")

# Import needed packages
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

# Import list of companies
companies <- read.csv("companies.csv", sep=";")

# Drop irrelevant columns
companies <- select(
  companies, 
  opened_on,
  closed
)

# Remove all companies opened before 2018-01-01 or after 2020-12-31
companies <- companies %>% filter(opened_on > "2018-01-01") %>% filter(opened_on < "2020-12-31")

# Count number of companies
companies.count <- nrow(companies) 

# Count number of companies without opened date
companies.usable <- sum(!is.na(companies$opened_on))

# Remove companies with missing data from the dataset (if there are any)
if(companies.count != companies.usable) {
  companies <- companies %>% drop_na(opened_on)
} 

# Remove no longer needed variables
rm(companies.count)
rm(companies.usable)

# Convert dates to months and years only (remove days)
dates <- c(companies$opened_on)
df <- data.frame(dates, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df$dates <- as.Date(df$dates, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
companies$opened_on <- format(df$dates, "%Y/%m")

# Remove no longer needed variables
rm(df)
rm(dates)

# Spit companies by years
companies.2018 <- companies[grep("2018/", companies$opened_on), ]
companies.2019 <- companies[grep("2019/", companies$opened_on), ]
companies.2020 <- companies[grep("2020/", companies$opened_on), ]

# Count number of newly opened companies per month
table(companies.2018$opened_on)
table(companies.2019$opened_on)
table(companies.2020$opened_on)

# Create graphs
ggplot(companies.2018) + aes(x = opened_on) + geom_bar()
ggplot(companies.2019) + aes(x = opened_on) + geom_bar()
ggplot(companies.2020) + aes(x = opened_on) + geom_bar()
```

Comment: Please include `companies` in your question using `dput()`. We can not reproduce your issue without data!

Comment: Or you can share the `.csv` file via a link to download. The plot you want is possible to create with `ggplot2`!

Comment: Dataset has been added

Comment: Fantastic Martin. I have added a possible solution to your issue using the data you shared!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach. I have slightly modified your code. What you want is a facet plot. You can do that with `ggplot2`. And the variables like year and month can be extracted directly in the dataframe. In order to format dates you can use `as.Date()` and to have the facets in proper format you can use `factor()`. Here the code that produces a plot similar to that showed. I have left some pieces of code because I do not know if you use those for other goals:

First, the data process:

```
# Import needed packages
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

# Import list of companies
companies <- read.csv("companies.csv", sep=";")

# Drop irrelevant columns
companies <- select(
  companies, 
  opened_on,
  closed
)
#Format date
companies$opened_on <- as.Date(as.character(companies$opened_on))
# Remove all companies opened before 2018-01-01 or after 2020-12-31
companies <- companies %>% filter(opened_on > as.Date("2018-01-01")) %>%
  filter(opened_on < as.Date("2020-12-31"))

# Count number of companies
companies.count <- nrow(companies) 

# Count number of companies without opened date
companies.usable <- sum(!is.na(companies$opened_on))

# Remove companies with missing data from the dataset (if there are any)
if(companies.count != companies.usable) {
  companies <- companies %>% drop_na(opened_on)
} 

# Remove no longer needed variables
rm(companies.count)
rm(companies.usable)
```

Now, we format, extract variables and compute counts:

```
#Extract year and month in same data
companies$Year <- format(companies$opened_on,'%Y')
companies$Month <- format(companies$opened_on,'%b')

#Compute counts
dfcounts <- companies %>% group_by(Year,Month) %>%
  summarise(N=n())
#Format months
dfcounts$Month <- factor(dfcounts$Month,levels = c('Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May',
                                                   'Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct',
                                                   'Nov','Dec'),ordered = T)
dfcounts$Year <- factor(dfcounts$Year)
```

Finally, we plot:

```
#Now plot
ggplot(dfcounts,aes(x=Year,y=N,group=Month,fill=Year))+
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity',position = position_dodge(0.9))+
  facet_wrap(.~Month,nrow = 1,strip.position = 'bottom')+
  theme(legend.position = 'top',
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle=45),
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_text(color='black',face='bold'),
        axis.title = element_text(color='black',face='bold'),
        strip.text = element_text(color='black',face='bold'),
        legend.text = element_text(color='black',face='bold'),
        legend.title = element_text(color='black',face='bold'),
        plot.title = element_text(color='black',face='bold',hjust=0.5))+
  geom_text(aes(label=N),position = position_dodge(0.9),vjust=-0.5,size=3,fontface='bold')+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma)+
  ggtitle('My title')
```

Output:

[image]